# Shell script leaving process after successful execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, nohup

I wrote a shell script which inturn calls other schell scripts using nohup. After the successful completion of the script, I still see Linux process running for the custom script I wrote.

contents of startAllComponents.sh

```
start_Server()
{   
SERVER_HOME=${1}
NOHUP_LOG_FILE=${2}
logmsg "Starting the server"
/usr/bin/nohup `${SERVER_HOME}/bin/server.sh >> ${NOHUP_LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ` &
sleep 5 
PID=`ps -ef|grep ${SERVER_HOME}/jvm |grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'`        
if [ "${PID}" = "" ]
then                
logmsg "Couldn't get the PID after starting the server"
else             
logmsg "****** Server started with PID: ${PID} ****** " 
fi
}

logmsg()
{
echo  "`date '+%b %e %T'` : $1"$'\n' >> /tmp/STARTUP`date '+%Y%m%d'`_.log
}

#### Send an email #####
sendEmail()
{               
RECIPIENTS="gut1kor@sample.com" 
SMTP="1.1.1.1:25"
mailx -s "$SUBJECT" -S "smtp=smtp://$SMTP" $RECIPIENTS < /tmp/STARTUP`date '+%Y%m%d'`_.log
}

##### Main #####
INTS[0]="/opt/server/inst01;/home/gut1kor/nohup.inst01.out"
INTS[1]="/opt/server/inst02;/home/gut1kor/nohup.inst02.out"
INTS[2]="/opt/server/inst03;/home/gut1kor/nohup.inst03.out"

echo "##### Bringing up servers on `hostname`. #####"$'\n' > /tmp/STARTUP`date '+%Y%m%d'`_.log

IS_TOTAL=${#INTS[@]}

logmsg "Total Servers are: ${IS_TOTAL}"

if [ "$IS_TOTAL" -gt "0" ]
then
for((i=0;i<IS_TOTAL;i++)) do
IFS=";" read -a arr <<< "${INTS[$i]}"
start_Server ${arr[0]} ${arr[1]}
done
fi
sendEmail
```

The script works as expected in bringin up the server instances but after the execution I see two processes for the script running for each instance.

```
[gut1kor@HOST1 startAll]$ ps -ef|grep startAllComponents.sh
gut1kor      63699     1  0 18:44 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./startAllComponents.sh
gut1kor      63700 63699  0 18:44 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./startAllComponents.sh
gut1kor      63889 61027  0 18:45 pts/2    00:00:00 grep startAllComponents.sh
```

Why these processes are still there even after the script execution is done? What changes should I make in the script?

Comment: How are you running the toplevel script initially?

Comment: "nohup Keeps a command running even after user logs off. The command will run as a foreground process unless followed by &. If you use nohup within a script, consider coupling it with a wait to avoid creating an orphan or zombie process."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly like due to the use of `nohup` utility. The problem with the using the command is, it forks a new process every time it is invoked from start_Server() function call.

From the `man` page

```
 nohup   No Hang Up. Run a command immune to hangups, runs the given 
         command with  hangup signals ignored, so that the command can 
         continue running in the background after you log out.
```

To kill all the process started by `nohup` you probably need to get the process id of the command started and kill it at the end of the script.

```
 /usr/bin/nohup $( ${SERVER_HOME}/bin/server.sh >> ${NOHUP_LOG_FILE} 2>&1 ) &
 echo $! >> save_pid.txt       # Add this line
```

At the end of the script.

```
 sendEmail

 while read p; do
 kill -9 $p
 done <save_pid.txt
```

Comment: @Etan Reisner I am running the script manually (./startAllComponents.sh)

Comment: @Inian Thanks for a detailed explanation. Yes, each time nohup is called it is creating 2 parent processes for the script startAllComponents.sh and one for the nohup command itself. I observed that if I kill the PID manually for the nohup command as suggested by you, the parent processes for the script are getting cleared. I will test the suggested change in the script and post the result. Thank you.